# Multithreaded application with database read - each thread unique records

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, multithreading, design-patterns

I have a .net application which basically reads about a million of records from database table each time (every 5 minutes), does some processing and updates the table marking the records as processed.

Currently the application runs in single thread taking about top 4K records from DB table, processes it, updates the records, and takes the next.

I'm using dapper with stored procedures. I'm using 4K records for retrieval to avoid DB table locks.

What would be the most optimal way for retrieving records in multiple threads and at the same time ensuring that each thread gets a new 4K records?

My current idea is that i would first just retrieve the ids of the 1M records. Sort the ids by ascending, and split them into 4K batches remembering lowest and highest id in a batch.
Then in each thread i would call another stored procedure which would retrieve full records by specifying the lowest and highest ids of records retrieved, process that and so on.

Is there any better pattern i'm not aware of?

Comment: If the DB access itself is ‘basic’ - ie. is I/O bound and can’t be optimized with concurrent access - it may be ‘better’ to mashall from/to a single DB access stream. This could allow, eg, a single ordering/walker.

Comment: This affirmation: " I'm using 4K records for retrieval to avoid DB table locks." it is not true and it is not the way that DB Lock (assuming MS SQL Server) works, there are elements as your ISOLATION LEVEL configured in your instance, in which way are you getting the rows from this table, etc.  There are many info about it on the web, my recommendation: Kalen Delaney blogs and books and Paul Randall, both can bring you a clear picture about it.

Comment: @GeovannyHernandez It is not for reading per se, but I skipped details about the part that is updating records (and this is the reason for 4K records). A stored procedure is called with an XML parameter containing all the id's of records that need to be marked as processed. I remember reading that 5K is the limit for table locks when doing bulk updates.

Comment: @AlexDee, I know that is not for reading per se, but my point is that MS SQL Server is already prepared for managing concurrent connections and DML operations, that limit of 5K it is the first time that I heard, are you not confusing this 5K with Lock scalation?

Comment: A better pattern would be reading the database using a single thread.

Comment: A question I have, that no one else seems to have asked is, what processing are you doing in your app that cannot be done in T-SQL? I've found very few use-cases where it's actually required for someone to do bulk-updates like you are doing by reading data out, and then updating it the way you describe. More context in what you're doing will help us recommend the best way forward, as fixing everything with a hammer, makes everything look like a nail, and you don't necessarily solve any problems going forward as your data scales

Comment: @AlexDee, I have an idea about what do you want to do, but, if I were you, would be good to test with one single thread and later with multiple and compare the performance, I am not sure that you will get an evident and remarkable difference between them.

Comment: @GeovannyHernandez Yes, i was talking about this. Taking only 4k to be safely under the 5k limit to avoid lock escalation from rows to the whole table.

Comment: Ok, so i will describe the system a bit so you will know what kind of processing is being done. Basically this is a notification system which means (and i'm simplifying a lot) Imagine a campaign for notification for specific customers. Each of those customers gets a campaign created every 30 mins or so. And then for those campaigns i'm retrieving subscribers that need to be notified. Imagine a campaign with 500k subscribers that need to be notified. Details about those subscribers are retrieved from database and then sent to a notification system queue via .net application.

Comment: And sorry for the confusing English. It is not my native language. :(

Comment: Just to double check, the present state of the database can handle multiple concurrent connections and sitting (ideally) on a fast disk like SSD? You really wouldn't want to kill it by queuing queries against it if it's a small cloud tier which can't handle concurrent stuff / or IO bound as @user2864740 called out.

Comment: The application and the database are both on prem, as is the notification service that the data is being handed to. And i have tested requesting data from database using about 4k records with multiple threads fine. But i was always getting the same top 4k results back. I would like to get unique results per thread and have some safety check if someone shuts down the app, the unsent data would be picked up next time.

Comment: @AlexDee please see my answer. Let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this problem interesting partly because I'm attempting to do something similar in principle but also because I haven't seen a super intuitive industry standard solution to it. Yet.

What you are proposing to do would work if you write your SQL query correctly.
Using `ROW_NUMBER / BETWEEN` it should be achievable.
I'll write and document some other alternatives here along with benefits / caveats.

#### Parallel processing

I understand that you want to do this in SQL Server, but just as a reference, Oracle implemented this as a keyword which you can query stuff in parallel.

Documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/parallel002.htm

SQL implements this differently, you have to explicitly turn it on through a more complex keyword and you have to be on a certain version:

A nice article on this is here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4939/how-to-force-a-parallel-execution-plan-in-sql-server-2016/

You can combine the parallel processing with SQL CLR integration, which would effectively do what you're trying to do in SQL while SQL manages the data chunks and not you in your threads.

#### SQL CLR integration

One nice feature that you might look into is executing .net code **in** SQL server. Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/introduction-to-sql-server-clr-integration

This would basically allow you to run C# code in your SQL server - saving you the read / process / write roundtrip. They have improved the continuous integration regarding to this as well - documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017

Reviewing the QoS / getting the logs in case something goes wrong is not really as easy as handling this in a worker-job though unfortunately.

#### Use a single thread (if you're reading from an external source)

Parallelism is only good for you if certain conditions are met. Below is from Oracle's documentation but it also applies to MSSQL: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/usingpe.htm#DWHSG024

> Parallel execution improves processing for:
>
> - Queries requiring large table scans, joins, or partitioned index scans
> - Creation of large indexes
> - Creation of large tables (including materialized views)
> - Bulk inserts, updates, merges, and deletes

There are also setup / environment requirements

> Parallel execution benefits systems with all of the following
>   characteristics:
>
> - Symmetric multiprocessors (SMPs), clusters, or massively parallel
>     systems
> - Sufficient I/O bandwidth
> - Underutilized or intermittently used CPUs (for example, systems where
>     CPU usage is typically less than 30%)
> - Sufficient memory to support additional memory-intensive processes,
>     such as sorts, hashing, and I/O buffers

There are other constraints. When you are using multiple threads to do the operation that you propose, if one of those threads gets killed / failed to do something / throws an exception etc... you will absolutely need to handle that - in a way that you keep until what's the last index that you've processed - so you could retry the rest of the records. 
With a single thread that becomes way simpler.

#### Conclusion

Assuming that the DB is modeled correctly and couldn't be optimized even further **I'd say the simplest solution, single thread is the best one. Easier to log and track the errors, easier to implement retry logic and I'd say those far outweigh the benefits you would see from the parallel processing.** You might look into parallel processing bit for the batch updates that you'll do to the DB, but unless you're going to have a CLR DLL in the SQL - which you will invoke the methods of it in a parallel fashion, I don't see overcoming benefits. Your system will have to behave a certain way as well at the times that you're running the parallel query for it to be more efficient.

You can of course design your worker-role to be async and not block each record processing. So you'll be still multi-threaded but your querying would happen in a single thread.

**Edit to conclusion**

After talking to my colleague on this today, it's worth adding that with even with the single thread approach, you'd have to be able to recover from failure, so in principal having multiple threads vs single thread in terms of the *requirement of recovery / graceful failure and remembering what you processed* doesn't change. How you recover would though, given that you'd have to write more complex code to track your multiple threads and their states.